# mod_rewrite to change "document root" based on query parameter?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to figure out how to set up a mod_rewrite rule so that a request for a page, with a URL parameter appended, determines the root from which that file is served.

Here's the setup.  In my "foo" directory I have "bar", "bar19", "bar27", etc.

Ideally I'd like to match on the first two characters of the "v" parameter.  So like this:

I would like a request for ..................... to be served from:

`www.example.com/foo/bar/something.html ..........  foo/bar/something.html
www.example.com/foo/bar/something.html?v=19xxx ... foo/bar19/something.html
www.example.com/foo/bar/something.html?v=27xxx ... foo/bar27/something.html`

Of course I would expect that if a value for "v" parameter that doesn't have a corresponding directory to 404.

I've done some Mod_Rewrite magic before, but I'm kind of stuck here.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `.htaccess` file in directory `/foo` with the following content. Of course you can also insert it into your `httpd.conf`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /foo

    # match query parameter v with two-digit value; capture
    # the value as %2 and the query string before and after v
    # as %1 and %3, respectively
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)v=(\d\d)[^&]*(&.*)?$

    # match path into "bar" and rest; insert two-digit value from
    # RewriteCond inbetween; append rest of query string without v value;
    # use case-insensitivity
    RewriteRule ^(bar)(.*)$ $1%2$2?%1%3 [NC]
</IfModule>
```

I think the key is to use captured values from the RewriteCond (accessible as %1, %2, etc.) **and** at the same time captured values from the RewriteRule itself (as usual $1, $2, etc.).

Comment: Most excellent!  I tried this before faa's answer because I was able to understand the heavy comments there. :-)  Thanks!